# is OSGI event handler thread safe

Tags: osgi

In my application we are using Event admin to post events and there are multiple events are fired simultaneously. These are handled by event handler. In event Handler have declared some private variables, and used in `handleEvent()` method.

Will it cause any thread safety issues? Declaring variables as private in event handler thread safe?

Answer (score 4):

Your event handler can be called on different threads simultaneously. So you have to ensure that access to any fields are handled safely.

Declaring variables private is completely unrelated to thread safety. It is not the access status that counts, it is the the simultaneous access that is important.

You regulate access with the synchronized keyword, locks, or lock-free constructs.

Comment: Thanks Peter, so it is possible that the fields declared at service(class) level can be accessed and modified at same time which will lead to uncertain behavior, because of this instead of synchronized or locks, we can just use method level local variables and use it.